# Django - How to make anchors change HTML list

Tags: python, html, jquery, django

I have the following snippet of HTML:

[image]

On my django webpage, i get a list that looks as follows:

[image]

Each "Part" anchor corresponds with a Part object in Python. Now, I'd like to make it so that when the user clicks on "Part_2", the datapoints of that Part are shown just below it.

On the image, the datapoints of the first part are shown within the nested list. I hard coded this. I looked into calling a python function with an argument from the template, but that is not possible.

What would be an easy way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this on the client side. First, create a `detail` element in your HTML and put a summary and the tags that you need (in this case, I'll be using a `<p></p>`) as childs:

```
<details>
  <summary>Part 1</summary>
  <p>Epcot is a theme park at Walt Disney World Resort featuring exciting attractions, international pavilions, award-winning fireworks and seasonal special events.</p>
</details>
```

What's inside the `summary` tag will represents the title and below that goes the hidden text that can be accessed by clicking in the arrow on the side of the title.

Then, make sure you filter in your function in `views.py` the parts by part_1 and part_2 and then pass them into your `context`. Lastly, render the items like this:

```
<details>
    <summary>Part 1</summary>
      {% for part in part_1 %}
         <p> {{ part.tag }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
</details>
```